# How to test print function in React and JavaScript with react-print library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using [react-to-print](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print) library for printing my component content.

I created a custom hook called `usePrint`:

```
import { useRef } from "react"
import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print"

export const usePrint = <T extends HTMLElement>() => {
  const componentRef = useRef<T>(null)

  const print = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
    pageStyle: "padding-inline: 2px",
    fonts: [
      {
        family: "Inter",
        source: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap",
      },
    ],
  })

  return { print, componentRef }
}
```

This hook works well, and I want to create a test with Jest and Testing Library to make sure that:

1. The `useReactToPrint` is called properly.
2. The PDF preview will be opened when the `print` is fired.

```
import { expect, jest } from "@jest/globals"
import { act, render, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react"
import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print"

import { usePrint } from "./usePrint"

jest.mock("react-to-print", () => ({
  useReactToPrint: jest.fn(),
}))

test("should the reference be null", () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => usePrint<HTMLDivElement>())
  expect(result.current.componentRef.current).toBeNull()
})

test("should inject useReactToPrint hook when call print", () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => usePrint<HTMLDivElement>())

  const { componentRef, print } = result.current

  act(() => print())
  
 // This assertion fails
  expect(useReactToPrint).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

The test fails with this log:

[image]